# Multiple font declarations with same font name but different font failes with different font-weight values

Tags: css, fonts

Following [this article](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/font-face_tip_define_font-weight_and_font-style_to_keep_your_css_simple/), I declared my various font faces under the same name but with different `font-weight` values (100, 400, 600 and 700). To do that, I took the code generated by Font Squirrel Font Generator and simply set the same value to all `font-family` instances.

For some reason though, 100 and 400 display the same thing (apparently regular), and 600 and 700 the same thing too (probably bold). Any idea why is that?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'proximanova';
    src: url('proximanova-bold.eot');
    src: url('proximanova-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('proximanova-bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('proximanova-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('proximanova-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('proximanova-bold.svg#proxima_nova_rgbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'proximanova';
    src: url('proximanova-light.eot');
    src: url('proximanova-light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('proximanova-light.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('proximanova-light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('proximanova-light.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('proximanova-light.svg#proxima_novalight') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100 !important;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'proximanova';
    src: url('proximanova-semibolditalic.eot');
    src: url('proximanova-semibolditalic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('proximanova-semibolditalic.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('proximanova-semibolditalic.woff') format('woff'),
         url('proximanova-semibolditalic.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('proximanova-semibolditalic.svg#proxima_novasemibold_italic') format('svg');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'proximanova';
    src: url('proximanova-regularitalic.eot');
    src: url('proximanova-regularitalic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('proximanova-regularitalic.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('proximanova-regularitalic.woff') format('woff'),
         url('proximanova-regularitalic.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('proximanova-regularitalic.svg#proxima_novaregular_italic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'proximanova';
    src: url('proximanova-semibold.eot');
    src: url('proximanova-semibold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('proximanova-semibold.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('proximanova-semibold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('proximanova-semibold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('proximanova-semibold.svg#proxima_novasemibold') format('svg');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'proximanova';
    src: url('proximanova-regular.eot');
    src: url('proximanova-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('proximanova-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('proximanova-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('proximanova-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('proximanova-regular.svg#proxima_nova_rgregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'proximanova';
    src: url('proximanova-lightitalic.eot');
    src: url('proximanova-lightitalic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('proximanova-lightitalic.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('proximanova-lightitalic.woff') format('woff'),
         url('proximanova-lightitalic.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('proximanova-lightitalic.svg#proxima_novalight_italic') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: Why did you write 2 'srcs' for each font-face? :\

Comment: Where are your CSS settings where you actually set the fonts on some elements, and where is the relevant HTML code?

Comment: You also need to specify the origin of the font and the method used to generate the font files, so that people can reconstruct the problem.

Comment: I edited my question to address these points. As for the exact CSS to set the fonts to elements it is irrelevant because no matter which element is targeted I can only obtain two different fonts no mater what font-weight values I set.

Comment: If you use the standard declaration (the css generated by Font Squirrel) does it work?
I faced a similar problem a couple of weeks ago with the standard css. It was a faulty generated font.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to try , kepping the same font-family names , is to set weights using the descriptive values
(`normal` - `bold` - `bolder` - `lighter`).

---

Otherwise consider the default **@font-face** functionality (importing a font assigning it a font-family name),

> Therefore the first thing would be to differentiate the `font-family:` descriptor (ex. proximanova-bold , proximanova-semi, etc.)

Extending this option , if you set  font-style and weight on specific fonts which  are already styled with those properties, you may lead into double-styling.
You should then set all font-weights & style to normal and just select the target `font-family:`

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'proximanova-bold';
    src: url('proximanova-bold.eot');
    src: url('proximanova-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('proximanova-bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('proximanova-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('proximanova-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('proximanova-bold.svg#proxima_nova_rgbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The author of the Proxima Nova font not occasionally separated it into many files. Each one of them supports only one set of properties like condense, weight, etc. The `font-weight` cannot change it even if you replace the `!important` declaration to `!very important` :)

Carefully reading this article about [Proxima Nova](http://www.marksimonson.com/fonts/view/proxima-nova) you can found that it supports for seven weights: Thin (100), Light (300), Regular (400), Semibold (600), Bold (700), Extrabold (800), and Black (900). You also can validated it [here](https://typekit.com/fonts/proxima-nova).

In your code you try, for example, to set weight 100 on the light font, but its weight is fixed 300 (seems almost like regular, but in fact is different). Take the 'Thin' font instead and you will get 100.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/whatisfirebug) with the Firefox browser as a tool to resolve this CSS font size problem. Firebug will show what CSS attributes were given precedence to assign a specific style characteristic of a web page element. Feedback from Firebug often reveals the solution to CSS related problems.

( Firebug example with images removed due to insufficient reputations points. )

Once you know how a particular element got its font-size value, then you can work on changing it to display how you want it to look.

BTW, Chrome has a similar tool that should provide similar feedback.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes a font will only support certain font-weights. I suggest looking at them to see which weights are supported.